# Path independence for complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for the name of the theorem that states path independence for complex integrals. In my book (Saff and sneider) it is only referred to as "theorem 6" but what can i call it if i want to refer to it on my finals?

Comment: Crazy idea, but you could just summarize the content of the theorem when you refer to it.

Comment: Depending on the precise statement of the theorem, it is probably a more or less direct variant of Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: Yeah i have seen some people refer to it as Cauchy's and indeed it is a consequence of it, just wasn't sure if it was right to use that name.