# Understanding Path Independence in Complex Analysis, Cauchy Integral Theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I don't understand the path independence in the Cauchy integral theorem which $0$ for a closed curve.

For example, consider Cauchy integral theorem on the closed curve $C$,  which is created by gluing $2$ non-identical or asymmetrical looking curves $C_1, C_2$. Since, it is on complex plain, then some values (images) of an arbitrary **holomorphic** function $f$ on both $C_1, C_2$ alog real and imaginary axis might be same (for example $a=4+1i$ is on $C_1$, and $b=4+4i$ on $C_2$, so the real part of $f(a)$ = real part of $f(b)$), but it os not always true, thus clockwise  sum, i.e. integration will not be equal to anticlockwise sum.

[image]

so while integrating on the closed curve** $C$, all the real x-components will be cancelled out (since $C_1, C_2$ are clockwise anti-clock-wise curve, respectively), but the y-axis or the complex component will not be a $0$!

What am I missing?

I am not saying Cauchy integral theorem is wrong, I am just trying to understand as newbie. I have seen other posts ( like, [1,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514376/complex-analysis-path-independence-condition) [2,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961415/why-is-the-independence-of-paths-for-complex-integrals-not-sufficient-enough-to), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438209/path-independence-for-complex-integrals)) on this forum, but didn't help.

EDIT:
Consider a situation, where all conditions for Cauchy integral theorem are met.

Comment: "Since, it is on complex plain, then all values of an arbitrary function f1 on both γ1,γ2 of x-axis is same but the complex component is not" This sentence doesn't make sense at all. Can you explain more clearly what you mean. I think your mistake is here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  It's hard to understand your description of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.  Can you draw a picture?  Also, “arbitrary” function is probably too broad.  Do you mean holomorphic?

Comment: OK, I'm still not understanding the situation you're describing.  Please give an explicit example of $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ and holomorphic $f$ such that $\int_{\gamma_1 - \gamma_2} f\,dz = bi$ for some $b \neq 0$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I have edited with picture, plz see.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang  function is not an issue, we consider a function that satisfy the condition of  Cauchy integral theorem , I have rephrased the post with a picture, plz see.

Comment: "(for example $a=4+1i$ is on $C_1$, and $b=4+4i$ on $C_2$, so the real part of $f(a)$ = real part of $f(b)$)" This statement is false. consider $f(z)=z^2$. Then, the real part of $f(a)$ is different from the real part of $f(b)$.

Comment: Rather than speculate about some arbitrary $f$, why don't you pick out a concrete example like $f(z) = z^2$ and work it out fully. You'll see that there is no contradiction anywhere. Then you can start to think about how it works in general.

Comment: @Raskolnikov u r correct, but then why integrating different lines gives same amount (but with different sign)? is there any other intuitive reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), here's a quick way to relate Cauchy's Integral Theorem and the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Define a holomorphic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then the integral over a loop $C$ is

$$\oint_C f dz = \oint (u + i v) d(x+iy) = \oint (u dx - v dy) + i \oint ( v dx + u dy )$$

Using Green's theorem, we can rewrite this as

$$\oint_C f dz = \iint_S \left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) dxdy + i \iint_S \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right) dxdy $$

where $S$ is the domain enclosed by the loop $C$. And since the function is holomorphic, both of these integrands are zero by the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

So, the reason Cauchy's integral theorem is true, is because of the strong restriction that the requirement of holomorphicity imposes on a function.